# How can we read data on odbc using generic queries with pyodbc?

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I'm connecting to ODBC using pyodbc and able to establish the connection with different types of databases like mysql, sql server. However, when I move further to read the names of the tables, or the column names in individual tables, I'm not able to get the result with single generic query, instead need to write the individual queries, like for mysql - "SHOW TABLES", for sql server - "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES".
So, it becomes difficult for me to connect to different databases using ODBC with single program. Is there any generic approach, or queries which are mapped to queries for individual databases. Like when we connect to database using ODBC through excel, we don't have to specify the queries and excel pulls the data on its own.

Below the sample code I am using:

```
import pyodbc
conn_str = f"DSN={dsn};UID={username};PWD={password}"
connection = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "Show Tables"
cursor.execute(query)
```

But the query needs to be changed based on the original database, which we want to be generic.
Please let me know, if you need any more information. Thanks in advance.
-Nandkishor

Comment: "Is there any generic approach, or queries which are mapped to queries for individual databases." - Yes, you can use a toolkit like [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/) to access different databases using common code. For example, the SQLAlchemy code to retrieve the table names (as per your example) would be `insp = sa.inspect(engine); print(insp.get_table_names())`

Comment: Thank you, Gord Thompson, I will try the solution and update here, if that serves the purpose.